# Add text to bitmap using byte array (know as add embedded subtitle to video)

Tags: java, android

i'm a newbie in Android programming 
I'm facing a problem when i want to add hard subtitle to recorded video.
Now i want to convert text to bitmap and add it to byte array of bitmap then save it.
Please help me solve this problem above, thanks so much

Update: i'm using lib gpuimage on Android follow hear https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage 
In [GPUImageRenderer.java](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/GPUImageRenderer.java):
It's open a Camera, and on *onPreviewFrame*, we received a *byte[] data*. So i want to convert a string to bitmap and add it on this array

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
    // convert data from YUV to RGBA
    // convert a string to byte[]
    // merge 2 byte array together
}
```

Comment: Hi could you please include some code, so we can understand what you are aiming at?

Comment: thanks your quick response. I'm updated my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check INDE Media Pack, it allows to add recording with effect applying to your app, it has several sample effects like Text Overlay to add text on a video while capturing, you can easily extend them: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

All effects are OpenGL based, so do not affect performance and let to have a good FPS in final video

[image]
[image]
[image]